# Как исправить ошибку "error cannot find symbol"?

Tags: java, компиляция

Только начал учиться программированию. При компиляции файла `Main.java`  выходит ошибка `error cannot find symbol`. Если я правильно понял, то он не взаимодействует с `Person.java`, а пытается выполнить всё в `Main.java`. Но как мне это решить? Всё ещё никак не могу понять.

**Main.java:**

```
 public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person dima = new Person();
        System.out.println(dima.height);
    }
}
```

**Person.java:**

```
 public class Person {
    int height = 189;
}
```

**Ошибка:**

```
E:\study\java> javac Person.java
E:\study\java> javac main.java
main.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
                Person dima = new Person();
                ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class main
main.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
                Person dima = new Person();
                                  ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class main
2 errors
```

Comment: Пожалуйста запустите в терминале `echo %CLASSPATH%` и пришлите что вывелось

Comment: Мне кажется, что в классе main не хватает импорта. Попробуйте добавить в начало `import Person`

Comment: Привет, можете почитать здесь https://pro-java.ru/java-dlya-nachinayushhix/import-paketov-v-java/ что указание `import` необязательно если используется полное имя класса, которое в нашем случае и есть `Person`, так что ошибка не в этом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такое поведение скорее всего связано с переменной `%CLASSPATH%` в которой перечислены папки где javac будет искать `.class` файлы для компиляции. По умолчанию эта переменная окружения не задана и тогда javac ищет `.class` файлы только в текущей папке.

Скорее всего у вас эта переменная была задана ранее (можно проверить при помощи `echo %CLASSPATH%`) и тогда текущую папку нужно указывать вручную, например через

```
javac main.java --class-path .
```

(`.` означает текущую директорию)

Если не хочется каждый раз вручную указывать `--class-path .` можно очистить `%CLASSPATH%` при помощи `set CLASSPATH=`

Обратите внимание что необязательно даже вызывать `javac Person.java`, компилятор автоматически скомпилирует `Person.java`

Вот пример запуска на моем компьютере (у меня линукс поэтому синтаксис немного отличается)

```
~/Workspace$ export CLASSPATH=
~/Workspace$ echo $CLASSPATH

~/Workspace$ javac Person.java 
~/Workspace$ javac main.java 
~/Workspace$ java main 
189
~/Workspace$ export CLASSPATH=/somedirectory
~/Workspace$ echo $CLASSPATH
/somedirectory
~/Workspace$ javac Person.java 
~/Workspace$ javac main.java 
main.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
        Person dima = new Person();
        ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class main
main.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
        Person dima = new Person();
                          ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class main
2 errors
~/Workspace$ javac main.java --class-path .
~/Workspace$ java main 
189
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё заработало

Answer (score 0):

И компиляция и выполнение проходят без ошибок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Удалось смоделировать такую же ошибку изменив в файле `main.java` в строке `Рerson dima = new Рerson();` английские заглавные "Пи" на русские заглавные "Эр". Посмотрите, может быть у вас подобная ошибка.