# При запуске Main.java выдаётся ошибка cannot find symbol

Tags: java, компиляция

В классе `Main` создается объект класса `Person`, при запуске выдаёт ошибку `cannot find symbol` и имя класса `Person`, не знаю в чём дело, пытаюсь запустить программу через командную строку в Windows. Код:

**`Main`:**

```java
package ClassesHomeWork;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Person nu = new Person();

        nu.id = 12;
        nu.login = "asddas";
        nu.password = "123123123";

        System.out.println(nu.login);
        System.out.println(nu.id);
        System.out.println(nu.password);
    }
}
```

**`Person`:**

```java
package ClassesHomeWork;

public class Person {
    public int    id;
    public String login;
    public String password;
}
```

**Ошибка:**

```
Main.java:6: error: cannot find symbol

        Person nu = new Person();
        ^
  symbol:   class Person 
  location: class Main

Main.java:6: error: cannot find symbol

        Person nu = new Person();
                        ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class Main

2 errors

error: compilation failed
```

Comment: Ваша проблема не воспроизводится, см. [скриншот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlWqF.png).  У вас действительно файл `Person.java` находится в директории пакета `ClassesHomeWork`? Приведите команды, при помощи которых вы компилируете Java код и пытаетесь его запустить.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Cant find symbol. \[X2\]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1348981/cant-find-symbol-x2)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как исправить "error cannot find symbol java"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1069296/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-error-cannot-find-symbol-java)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что при компиляции файла `Main.java` компилятор не может найти файл `Person.class`. Потому, что он компилирует столько файлов, сколько указано в командной строке, не больше и не меньше. Правда можно сделать так, чтобы он автоматически компилировал зависимые классы. Для этого надо использовать опцию компилятора `-sourcepath`  и указать где находятся зависимые классы.

> Опция `-sourcepath` сообщает компилятору Java, где найти входные исходные файлы.  Если опция `-sourcepath` не указана, `javac` будет использовать путь к классам пользователя для поиска как файлов классов, так и исходных файлов.  Итак, мы можем заменить параметр `-sourcepath` на параметр `-classpath` или `-cp`.
> Однако этот подход имеет свои ограничения: команда `javac` компилирует только необходимые классы и опускает другие исходные файлы.

Можно также использовать звёздочку вместо названия файла для указания всех файлов. Тогда компилятор откомпилирует все файлы в директории.

> Команда `javac` также поддерживает подстановочный знак (*) для компиляции нескольких исходных файлов в одном каталоге.

Для этого достаточно запустить

```
>javac *.java
```

и тогда он откомпилирует все классы в текущей директории.

Comment: Вообще у создателя вопроса должно быть следующая проблема:  
1. создать папку ./ClassesHomeWork  
2. cd ClassesHomeWork  
3. создать Main.java (как в примере)  
4. создать Person.java (как в примере)  
5. если компилировать находясь в папке ClassesHomeWork (javac Main.java) не компилится -- полагаю javac пытается найти класс "Person" по пути относительно текущего с учетом пакета (т.е. "./ClassesHomeWork/Person.java" но мы уже в ClassesHomeWork  
6. решение: "cd .. && javac ClassesHomeWork\Main.java"

Comment: @RomaS Не компилится, потому что javac не может найти `Person.java` в исходниках. Если удалить ссылки на класс `Person` в `Main.java` , то должно компилиться.

Comment: пруф
https://ibb.co/x8GFJ2c

Comment: @RomaS Этого не достаточно, нужно ещё вывести переменные среды.

Comment: Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим ваш код лежит по следующему пути:

- D:\my-projects\ClassesHomeWork\Main.java
- D:\my-projects\ClassesHomeWork\Person.java

для компиляции вам следует делать так (cmd):

- `D:`
- `cd D:\my-projects\`
- `javac ClassesHomeWork\Main.java`
- `java ClassesHomeWork.Main`

Comment: Не имеет значения из какой папки запускать javac. Так можно делать, только надо добавить опцию компилятору `-cp .` . Без этого компилиться не будет :)

Comment: может быть вы какой то другой компилятор используете я не знаю конечно, но  у меня всё ровно так и происходит, использую openjdk 11.0.2